# Making a table that has all possible combinations

Tags: r, excel

I am trying to make a table that has every combination of 1 and 0, in lists of 5. For example,

11111
11110
10111
10011,

and so on. The order does matter. I am trying to do it in Excel currently but all the videos I am watching on the topic are using Power Query or another way that my Excel seems to be missing.

Is there a simple way to do this in Excel or even R? I have some R experience but would prefer it to be in Excel. Thanks so much for any guidance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing could be thought of as "all the 5 digit numbers in binary", which can describe the integers from 0 to 31. There's a built-in function in one of the packages that comes with R (`R.utils`) that converts from integer to binary. So:

```
R.utils::intToBin(0:31)
```

Result

```
 [1] "00000" "00001" "00010" "00011" "00100" "00101" "00110" "00111" "01000" "01001" "01010" "01011" "01100"
[14] "01101" "01110" "01111" "10000" "10001" "10010" "10011" "10100" "10101" "10110" "10111" "11000" "11001"
[27] "11010" "11011" "11100" "11101" "11110" "11111"
```

---

In Excel, make a column with the numbers from 0 to 31. Then next to that, put in `DEC2BIN(A1,5)` and drag down.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `expand.grid()` function in R is designed to "[c]reate a data frame from all combinations of the supplied vectors or factors", in this case:

```
> expand.grid(lapply(numeric(5), function(x) c(0,1)))
   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5
1     0    0    0    0    0
2     1    0    0    0    0
3     0    1    0    0    0
4     1    1    0    0    0
5     0    0    1    0    0
6     1    0    1    0    0
7     0    1    1    0    0
8     1    1    1    0    0
9     0    0    0    1    0
10    1    0    0    1    0
11    0    1    0    1    0
12    1    1    0    1    0
13    0    0    1    1    0
14    1    0    1    1    0
15    0    1    1    1    0
16    1    1    1    1    0
17    0    0    0    0    1
18    1    0    0    0    1
19    0    1    0    0    1
20    1    1    0    0    1
21    0    0    1    0    1
22    1    0    1    0    1
23    0    1    1    0    1
24    1    1    1    0    1
25    0    0    0    1    1
26    1    0    0    1    1
27    0    1    0    1    1
28    1    1    0    1    1
29    0    0    1    1    1
30    1    0    1    1    1
31    0    1    1    1    1
32    1    1    1    1    1
```